# htaccess rewrite rule - Allowing all forms of capitlisation

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the moment in my .htaccess I have the following:

```
RewriteRule ^register$ ./Secure/register.php
RewriteRule ^Register$ ./Secure/register.php
```

Obviously if they go to /Register or /register it redirects them but is there a way for it to just take any capitalisation, for example /ReGiStEr and have that redirect without writing a rule for every possible outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`nocase|NC`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) flag

```
RewriteRule ^register$ ./Secure/register.php [NC]
```